# Conditionally filter Knockout observeablearray

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of orders that will display either a full or filtered dropdown list of items, depending on whether the Cancel property in my view model is true or not. I'm having a problem here because as it stands, my options list will only be filtered if my condition is true for all orders. I need the value of the cancel property to transfer to the modal, but it seems to default to false. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

This is part of my html:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Orders">
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#Modal" data-bind="click: $parent.SetCurrentOrderInfo($data)">
            <span data-bind="if: $data.Change">Change</span>
            <span data-bind="if: $data.Cancel"> Cancel </span>
        </a></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Type of Request</p>
            <select id="RequestType" class="form-control" data-bind='options: FilteredRequestTypes, optionsText: "Text", value: SelectedRequestType'></select>
        </div>
```

This is part of the knockout:

```
self.Orders = ko.observableArray(OrdersViewModel.Orders);
self.RequestTypes = ko.observableArray(OrdersViewModel.RequestTypes);
self.FilteredRequestTypes = ko.observableArray();
self.CurrentOrderNumber = ko.observable();
self.Cancel = ko.observable();

self.SetCurrentOrderInfo = function (order) {
        self.CurrentOrderNumber = order.OrderNumber;
        self.Cancel = order.Cancel;
        if (order.Cancel) {
            self.FilteredRequestTypes = self.RequestTypes().filter(function (c) {
                return c.ParentKey == "Cancellation";
            });
        }
        else {
            self.FilteredRequestTypes = self.RequestTypes;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Knockout observable values will act as a function. This is how you assign and get a value from it.

```
self.Cancel = ko.observable(false);
// ...
// ...
var isCancelled = self.Cancel(); // to get its value
self.Cancel(true) // to assign new value
```

So this is what you need to do in the javascript code:

```
self.SetCurrentOrderInfo = function (order) {
  self.CurrentOrderNumber(order.OrderNumber);
  self.Cancel(order.Cancel);
  if (self.Cancel()) {
    self.FilteredRequestTypes(self.RequestTypes().filter(function (c) {
      return c.ParentKey === "Cancellation";
    }));
  }
  else {
    self.FilteredRequestTypes(self.RequestTypes());
  }
};
```